# Xamarin without Windows Pro

Tags: windows, xamarin, amd-processor

I have an HP laptop with 6 GB ram with an AMD chipset using VS 2017 community and have Xamarin installed.  I am NOT using Windows Pro and I am unable to get an emulator to work properly.  Before investing more money in a new computer, I am trying to make this laptop do the job.  I am wondering if it is the AMD chipset or lack of Windows Pro or both that is the problem.

Comment: Google's AVD-based Android emulators do not use Hyper-V (just the Microsoft created Android images do). You will not be able to use Intel's HAXM acceleration to get the fast x86-based Android images to work, but the ARM ones will run (albeit slowly). You can also look at GenyMotion x86 emulators as they are VirtualBox based and do not require Hyper-V or HAXM.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Hyper-V to run an Android emulator. What your hardware needs to support is at least Intel-VT or something similar. If it does not support it, use a real device to test, which is recommend any ways.

Answer (score -1):

the android emulator needs Hyper-V, and that role can't be activated on some Windows 10 editions (like `Home`). The system requirements for Hyper-V are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-requirements . You'll need either `Professional`, `Education` or `Enterprise`.

Comment: Hyper-V is not needed. HAXM requires Intel VT-x, VT and vmx extensions, which are only found on Intel CPUs.

Comment: Xamarin seems to disagree with you: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/

Comment: The Visual Studio Android Emulator is discontinued.

Comment: are you sure? The Xamarin Android Player is discontinued, but it seems the VS emulator is still included in VS 2017: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/34d06dea-0bb4-4c67-a115-d739f7be91c7/visual-studio-2017-emulator-for-android?forum=vssetup&prof=required . And it seems Hyper-V is still a requirement for it.

Comment: If you actually launch it you will see that it is discontinued :)